# Não consigo corrigir esse erro java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

estou criando um app simples para mostrar as imagens numa especie de galeria
mas não estou conseguindo mostrar as imagens na view pelo adapter. Sempre da esse erro NullPointerException

Classe Adapter:

```
public class AdapterGaleriaFragment extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    List<ImageDataModel> lista;
    public AdapterGaleriaFragment(Context ctx, List <ImageDataModel> lista){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista != null ? lista.size():0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter,parent, false);


        //tentativa de mostrar as imagens através do adapter
        ImageDataModel img = lista.get(position);

        File imgFile = new  File(img.getImagePath());
        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            ImageView myImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }else{
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bowser2);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Classe para carregar o caminho das imagens junto com o titulo:

```
public class LoaderImg {


    public static List<ImageDataModel> allImages = new ArrayList<ImageDataModel>();

    public static List<ImageDataModel> gettAllImages(Context ctx) {

        //Remove older images to avoid copying same image twice

        allImages.clear();
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage = null, imageName;

        //get all images from external storage

        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME };

        cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

        column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            imageName = cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name);

            allImages.add(new ImageDataModel(imageName, absolutePathOfImage));

        }

        // Get all Internal storage images

        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

        column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            imageName = cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name);

            allImages.add(new ImageDataModel(imageName, absolutePathOfImage));
        }

        return allImages;
    }

}
```

log:

> ```
> Process: com.example.alex_sama.galeriramesmo, PID: 12026
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
> at adapter.AdapterGaleriaFragment.getView(AdapterGaleriaFragment.java:63)
> at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2435)
> at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
> at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1071)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
> at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1071)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
> at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2625)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5281)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:375)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
> Process: com.example.alex_sama.galeriramesmo, PID: 12026
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
> at adapter.AdapterGaleriaFragment.getView(AdapterGaleriaFragment.java:63)
> at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2435)
> at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
> at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1071)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
> at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1071)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
> at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2625)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5281)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:375)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro diz:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

Seguindo seu código, o `setImageBitmap` é da variável `myImage` com o id `R.id.imageView`.

Tudo leva a crer que o id `R.id.imageView` não está sendo encontrado no layout `R.layout.layout_adapter` e consequentemente a variável `myImage` está `null`.

Qualquer coisa posta o XML do layout `R.layout.layout_adapter`.

Comment: obrigado, o erro estava mesmo no xml!